# Java JTabbedPane or how to get the custom Object that created the Tab

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I am often struggling with the same problem of custom Objects that creates a e.g. gui Component. And I never know what is the best way to get from the gui Component back to the object.

So multiple hacks and tricks are welcome.

Let me explain it to you:

**This is my custom Object I need to find afterwards**

```java
public class MyObject {
    int yearOfBirth;
    String name;
    public MyObject(int yearOfBirth, String name) {
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getYearOfBirth() {
        return yearOfBirth;
    }
    
    public Component getPanel() {
        Component panel1 = makeTextPanel("This is the personal tab of "+name);
        return panell;
    }
}
```

**This is where I need to find it through the Tab I am focusing**

```java
public class MyTabControl implements ChangeListener {
    JTabbedPane myTabPane = new JTabbedPane();
    
    public MyTabControl(){
        //This will add a Listener for clicking on one Tab
        myTabPane.addChangeListener(this);
    }
    
    public void oneMoreTab(MyObject myObject) {
        myTabPane.addTab(myObject.name, myObject.getPanel())
        
    }
    
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Focus of Tab changed");
        int actualFocusedTabIndex = myTabPane.getSelectedIndex();
        Component acutalFocusedComponent = myTabPane.getComponentAt(actualFocusedTabIndex);
        //This works fine, I can get the Tab. Or at least the Component.
        //But how do I get the yearOfBirth or better the Object itself?
        int yearOfBirthOfTheSelectedTab = ???
    }
}
```

**This is just the main function**

```jsp
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Commands to start and create the GUI
    
    MyTabControl myTabControl = new MyTabControl();
    
    MyObject mother = new MyObject(1960, "Helen");
    myTabControl.oneMoreTab(mother);
    
    MyObject father = new MyObject(1955, "James");
    myTabControl.oneMoreTab(father);
}
```

**EDIT:**

**1 not working solution: Extend Component class**

*I have tried to extend the class Component. But this will create a failure (see comment in code):*

```jsp
public class ComponentWithExtras extends Component {
   MyObject myObject;
   public void addMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
      this.myObject = myObject;
   }
}


// The following line will create failure: Can't cast Component to ComponentWithExtras
ComponentWithExtras componentWithExtras = (ComponentWithExtras) myObject.getPanel();
componentWithExtras.addMyObject(myObject);
myTabPane.addTab(myObject.name, componentWithExtras);
```

Comment: What's wrong with saving a reference to the caller in the tab?

Comment: Googled it, but I dont get what you mean. Can you show me an example? Or tell me what command to place in my code and where.

Comment: Create a Map<JComponent, MyObject>. Then, in your oneMoreTab()-method, put the just created tab and MyObject into the map. Then, you can from elsewhere lookup the MyObject that was used to create the panel.

Comment: This is how I already solved it. But is very unsatisfying, as I need to take care of the Map too. I need to put and remove entries parallel to the tab managment. I was hoping for a way to solve it without "double" managing, as the jtabbedpane is already kind of a Map itself. I was hoping to solve this with an e.g. extended class of JTabbedPane / Component or a method of JTabbedPane I dont know yet. But thank you very much of course!

Comment: If your tab component is your own class, you can extend it with a MyObject member, and do it that way.

Comment: I have tried that. See the Edit in my Main Post.